# Json Object to Div Html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, object

Here is my Json data

```
    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
        From_Id: 5
        Message: "
        ↵   did you have dinner???"
        Started_Date: "2014-07-29 11:29:41"
        To_Id: 5
        Upadted_Date: "2014-07-29 03:29:41"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        From_Id: 5
        Message: "ya i did what about you???
        ↵   "
        Started_Date: "2014-07-29 11:51:41"
        To_Id: 1
        Upadted_Date: "2014-07-29 03:51:41"
    __proto__: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    9: Object
    10: Object
    11: Object
    length: 12
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

I want to add each `message` from object to div `message_data` one after other....i have used the code below...so that `message_data` div contains all the messages....

```
            var obj = eval(data);

            console.log(obj);
            $.each(obj, function (index,Object) {

                var Id = Object.Message;
                $('#message_data').html(Id).toString();
            });
```

But it is displaying only the last object `message`.. how do i fix this???

Note: Iam using this inside timer `function` so i can not use `append` ,, which keeps adding same contents after `timer seconds...`

Comment: You are looping and override the underlying `html` content, so will display only last message.

Comment: you are replacing all data in div with the current value that is problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you are replacing `innerHTML` of div with current object Message in `each` loop. So in last it just has the last object Message.

Try this

```
var msg = '';
$.each(obj, function (index,Object) {
    msg += Object.Message;
});

$('#message_data').html(msg).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `html` function replaces whatever is inside the target element. Use the `append` function instead...

```
$('#message_data').append(Id);
```

The only thing you have to do is replace the `html` function with the `append` function.

you can even use the index parameter in order to access the current value being enumerated, see below...

```
       $.each(obj, function (index,Object) {
            var msg = obj[index].message;
            $('#message_data').append(msg);
        });
```

#### [JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nDCH8/)

Comment: I can not use `append` because it keeps adding same contents again and again.....I want to load it only once....

Comment: @Friend it's adding the same object again and again because your `each` function logic is wrong. It has nothing to do with append. I'll update the answer

Comment: your both answers have no issues....but i have same problem... after loading all object contents it loads the data again.. because iam using this inside 'Timer script...' so it has fetch data every 5 seconds....So using `html` is better then append i gues.. what do u think???

Comment: @Friend obviously, that was the most important piece of information and you omitted it from your question

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple fix:

Don't use eval..

```
var obj = {};
try {
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
} catch(e) { console.log(e.message); };
```

"console.debug" function helps you inspect objects better..

```
console.debug(obj);
$.each(obj, function (index,Object) {
    var msg = Object.Message;
    $('#message_data').append('<p>' + msg.toString() + '</p>');
});
```

You can also try this:
console.debug(obj);

```
 for(var o in obj) {
    var msg = obj[o];
    $('#message_data').append('<p>' + msg.toString() + '</p>');
 });
```

Cheers...!

Comment: If you're trying to visualize the process, you can append at intervals.